# how can I retain the br tags in getSelection().toString in IE11?

Tags: javascript, range, internet-explorer-11, contenteditable, getselection

Currently the `execCommand 'forecolor'` command creates a `<font>` tag with the selected color (which is deprecated). I would like to create a `<span>` tag instead.

I'm trying to write my own function to do so, this is what I currently do:

```
var sel = getSelection();

var range = sel.getRangeAt(0);

var selectedText = getSelection().toString();

document.execCommand("delete");

var newNode = document.createElement("span");

newNode.innerHTML = selectedText;
newNode.style.color = currentColor;

range.insertNode(newNode);

range.setStart(newNode, 0)
range.setEnd(newNode, newNode.childNodes.length);

sel.removeAllRanges;
sel.addRange(range);
```

**The issue I'm facing**: when there are one or more `<br>` tags within the selection they are lost. I know that the `toString()` function strips the tags off, but how can I keep these tags and the text?

**UPDATE**: unfortunately I realized that altough adding \n at every `br` works, when you try to move the caret in the div with the keyboard the \n character is considered: so, for example, if I want to delete an empty line I'll have to push backspace twice to send the caret up one line. I consider the issue still unsolved.

Answer (score 3):

you need to convert every newline char to a `<br>` tags

change this line:

```
newNode.innerHTML = selectedText;
```

to this:

```
newNode.innerHTML = selectedText.replace(/(?:\r\n|\r|\n)/g, '<br />');
```

this will replace every form of newline to a `<br>` tag so you'll get the correct structure

Here's a working example:

```js
// fix for IE11
// pasteHtmlAtCaret("<br />\n");

$('button').click(() => {
  var sel = window.getSelection();

  var range = sel.getRangeAt(0);

  var selectedText = getSelection().toString();

  document.execCommand("delete");

  var newNode = document.createElement("span");

  newNode.innerHTML = selectedText.replace(/(?:\r\n|\r|\n)/g, '<br />');
  newNode.style.color = 'orange';

  range.insertNode(newNode);

  range.setStart(newNode, 0)
  range.setEnd(newNode, newNode.childNodes.length);

  sel.removeAllRanges;
  sel.addRange(range);
});
```

```css
p {
  background: #212121;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p contenteditable="true">
  This content should be edtiable,<br> and when selecting text and clicking the button,<br> the text should get colored and NOT mess up newlines
</p>

<button>
color selection and keep linebreaks
</button>
```

As @devamat mentions in his answer, **IE11** replaces `<br>` elements with spaces instead of newlines. In order to fix this for **IE11**, change the caret character using the following function:

```
pasteHtmlAtCaret("<br />\n");
```

which should fix the problem for **IE11** as well

Comment: @devamat  added a working example to show how this should work. If that didn't work for you, tell me what's the behaviour you saw that you didn't expect

Comment: Thanks for adding the snippet. On Firefox it's working, but when I try on IE11 (unfortunately I need it on IE11) I get an error: color selection and keep linebreaks   


Error: {
  "message": "Syntax error",
  "filename": "https://stacksnippets.net/js",
  "lineno": 24,
  "colno": 30
}

Comment: I found this in the meantime... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22093776/cant-get-new-lines-of-selected-text-on-ie11

Comment: It says that IE11 replaces the newline with a space, but actually I don't see any space either in the result.

Comment: I found a solution: just add \n after every br and add it again when I replace them. See main post for more.

Comment: @devamat cool! nice find! also added it to my answer for a complete solution

Comment: Unfortunately I realized that altough the trick works, when you try to move the caret in the div with the keyboard the \n character is considered: so, for example, if I want to delete an empty line I'll have to push backspace twice to send the caret up one line.

Answer (score 1):

IE11 won't give the newlines when using getSelection().toString() or range.toString(). The solution for me was to add a \n after every `br` the user adds to the contentEditable, and then when replacing the new lines making sure to add \n again.

So when the user adds a `br`:

```
pasteHtmlAtCaret("<br />\n");
```

When I replace it:

```
newNode.innerHTML = selectedText.replace(/(?:\r\n|\r|\n)/g, '<br />\n');
```